# Can't pass the ".pdf" file using the postman request body

Tags: postman

I have sent a text file successfully through the body request using form-data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoLBm.png)

but if I am trying to send rather than test a file through the body request using form-data, I am getting 503 error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKfOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the initial test, you seem to have passed text file. where as in your second request it is a binary file (pdf).

Server seems to not able to handle binary attachments.

if server is written in python you should use `open('filename', 'wb'/'rb')`  (`b` here means binary/utf-8).